# Adding Sharepoint Framework WebPart Programatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, spfx

I have created a SharePoint Framework webpart and have been able to add it to the app catalog in our web application. I then can add it by manually clicking the "Add an App" link inside of a site collection but was hoping to find a way to programmatically add this app/webpart to multiple site collections.

Is there any options available to SharePoint On-Premise applications or is the only way to add a SPFx app to a site collection by manually doing so? Seems like there is plenty of discussion regarding SPO but unfortunately those discussions do not help with Sharepoint On-Premise.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There was somewhere a comment from a spfx developer that this feature will be only for SharePoint Online available and maybe (!) for SharePoint 2019 but defenitly not for SP2016 on premise. (The comment was somewhere here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment unfortunately they changed the feedback system and it disappeared).

Comment: Shame that the comments are no longer available, as well as sounding like no additional changes will come to Sharepoint Framework for 2016 On-Premise.

Answer (score 0):

Tick the box "Make this solution available to all sites in the organization" when adding the package to the app catalogue. This should make the web part tenant scoped.

To get this checkbox, you need `"SkipFeatureDeployment": true` in your package-solution.json like so:

```
"solution": {
  "name": "<web part name in app catalogue>",
  "id": "38862200-dfec-4997-a28d-2589df4fef16",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "skipFeatureDeployment": true
}
```

[Read more](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Announcing-Tenant-Scoped-Deployment-of-SharePoint-Framework/td-p/94703) about tenant scoped solutions.

Comment: While I appreciate your response, that approach is specific to Sharepoint Online, and not Sharepoint 2016 (On-premise). If this approach was available to the On-Premise version, it would definitely get me what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm only working with SPO, but I thought this might do the trick even on-prem. You did say "Any help is appreciated" so I gave it a shot. Obviously it didn't work. I'm sorry if I wasted your time.